# Structure in C programming

Tags: c#, c

Can a structure in C programming be considered/compared to a class in C# OOP ?
I am asking this because a structure has different data types which are similar to C#  OOP classes.

Comment: TL;DR- I'd better not.

Comment: A struct in a language with OO support is typically to be regarded as a class with all members public.

Answer (score 2):

There are structures in C# also, which would apply to those in C. They are value-types however and therefor not nullable. Classes however also exist in C# and have a totally different use as they are reference-types.

Comment: C++? Do you mean C#? `struct` and `class` are really the same in C++.

Comment: Pardon me, but isn't it like OP is asking for the _relation_ between `C` and `C#` _structures_?

Comment: But you're talking about classes in C++, and what you're saying about them is wrong. `s/C++/C#/`

Comment: @juanchopanza Ahh, I see what you mean and edited it properly.